# What does this operation do in matlab?

Tags: matlab

This is very basic, but please forgive me since I'm only familiar with python and am trying to translate this code over from matlab. Basically, I have two variables:

```
var1 = [139;
140;
142;
143;
144;
154;
156;
157;
158;
159;
184;
185;
186;
187;
188;
189;
190;
191;
192]


var2 = [11;
12;
12;
15;
10;
8;
7;
10;
9;
6;
10;
9;
8;
15;
5;
17;
15;
18;
14;
18;
16;
13;
13;
17;
19;
4;
15;
18;
1;
4;
2;
3;
3;
1;
9]
```

All fine and good. Except that there is a separate variable, call it var3, which is defined as:

```
var3 = var1(var2);
```

which results in the value:

```
var3 = [184;
185;
185;
188;
159;
157;
156;
159;
158;
154;
159;
158;
157;
188;
144;
190;
188;
191;
187;
191;
189;
186;
186;
190;
192;
143;
188;
191;
139;
143;
140;
142;
142;
139;
158]
```

I'm confused as to what operation is occurring to get this resultant value of var3. Moreover, what would the equivalent operation be in python? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Answer (score 1):

It actually likes this

```
var3 = [ var1( var2(1) ) ; var1( var2(2) ) ; ... ; var1( var2( //last value ) ) ]
```